# Display port on GPU no longer displaying on monitor, display settings detects monitor but says its now 640x480 now. (AMD GPU)

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, gpu, amd-radeon

So as the title says, My secondary monitor (connected via displayport to hdmi adapter) is no longer working. My main display (connected directly via HDMI) is working perfectly fine. My secondary monitor is flashing the power saving mode screen and when I go to the display settings on windows it shows that my secondary monitor is detected but shows as a 640x480 monitor (both monitors are 1080).

Things I've done so far:

- switch cables (both cables work fine and both monitors work fine)
- roll back drivers (nothing happened)
- update drivers (nothing happened)

I'm fairly stuck on what to do now.

For those who need the extra info, the graphics card I'm using is an AMD rx 570 from ASUS.

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`  ?

Comment: You have ruled out the adapter I presume?

Comment: I can confirm that the adapter works, there was a single instance where the secondary monitor worked but I couldn't replicate it.